# How can I calculate internet speed?

Tags: performance, networking, client-server, bandwidth

I want to calculate internet speed in embedded device. In my researches on the internet, I saw that in order to measure internet speed, I had to download data from a server and calculate according to the download time. But this creates a lot of data usage and tires the device. Are there any other methods I can use other than that?

If there is no other way, What is the optimal data size to download from server?

Thank you.

Comment: "_I saw that in order to measure internet speed, I had to download data from a server and calculate according to the download time._" That only measures the speed to/from that server and the server processing time. You will find greatly varying speed to/from different servers and places on the Internet. The Internet is just a bunch of companies connecting to each other in a giant patchwork (there is no backbone as many people seem to assume).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the only possible way to test data transfer, at least correctly. Simple ideas that can be used as speedtest:

- Load image(s), check when it's fully loaded and calculate time difference divided by image size.
- Make GET request which responds to you with desired chunk of data and on response calculate difference divided by response size.
- Create POST request and send randomly generated data in it and on response calculate difference divided by image size.
- Create websocket and send ping->pong messages. (Websocket used instead of HTTP request because of its lower latency and stability)

You should also take a look that in all of those tests data compression and caching should be disabled and that they may be affected by ping.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but there isn't an "Internet speed" because devices and applications do many things on Internet. You should start understanding and explaining what your device does and what you are trying to measure. If your device receives a video stream, you are not interested in the TCP bandwidth or latency. If your device sends small data packets against one server, you should test the average response time between your device and that server with messages roughly the same size.
Moreover, an embedded device is often limited and should not be used to measure because you cannot say if the speed is throttled by the network or by the device itself. So, you should replace your device with a fast-enough pc.
If the device uses a wireless network (wifi, 4G, ...) the speed can be variable and you should take many measures and calculate an average